# least square approximation in spline space

Tags: functional-analysis, least-squares, spline

I am confused about how to obtain the least squares estimator of this problem:
$$
\inf\{||s-\lambda||_2:s\in S_{k,v}\}=||P_k\lambda-\lambda||_2\tag{1}
$$
where $||\lambda||_2=\{\int_0^1\lambda^2(x)dx\}^{1/2}$, and $S_{k,v}$ is called the class of all B-splines of degree $v$ with $k$-equspaced knots. This [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272481/1-s2.0-S0047259X00X01054/1-s2.0-0047259X91900616/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEG4aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDjZdPIQN4QX8ecZklCWO3r4BsQ8R8%2BVQb3LyXR8N%2FMUwIgFOHTYnDRv244C2urgXkw7ZXaU5j7QlBBkBqSJ8TOwYgqvQMI1v%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDCijXq28Lmfj5PUGFSqRAzZc20D1G3qEYKOlnQQ3TeKK2ItRGZDI6sBShO9M%2BDBCNHRr2cugPaTr16b3ixHN8rY0wzVVLrEFDE2bhbF9TkixWz5LFVGQMzwxqaCqvw%2BYCu7a5x5xUtpRwhZSG4hM51LDvvXEKUNt6F5hpKF%2FpAvqOFZfV4mCxOMMocsp5iFUehx9EIHwQDvxs8UViCeU3MXptMl18tNTU2DOYjMZcHq2COCNVB4Z7j%2F%2F9fc8NhRnlYKJZDT6N95ovKqCQ2swUpNFTYWv5xPMuzNITn1jnjsf%2BEYhRPwCBkbcLw5Z%2BTxB6VFnHT4NxyB8aWVRWzLFsX6Fk2%2FZ3EoydFSAaJ2mc5%2FBvH9ZOEThHIKENHTafw%2FhHwgkY2U9hGffhxzP1ToM8mvBJLWmyZS0hZG5DSmXfIW%2BGORd9ZJAi7rVG0Rd9EAxZ8UXXUCv0kMS%2BPzPgwV%2BQFZhtCBQUi7fnq3q%2F1vHNXlO7Y9YWDo4qpjdwF5IpyiC%2BKomqEzIKMuVswQdfqU2A%2FaDeledQxe6qRCQ4RD9V1wDMLHzp%2FAFOusBWpyxGImrL6h9FzG1%2BkwxjF9ohyZoPpJPvxhCa1vs0SBiKnblhSS%2BithFP0JGpOTx%2FaBVUE0tUefS%2BbJ2jXujcx0Pi4Sx9hi0%2FyuF8UGolh1HlMpVCgQoA3LrEjXs%2F0xqBFBjEfxGOG1HVowuiMOqcbAbWpIDrjHWlSPS7mNypajyp0Nv%2F5dzowszc%2FiTE8pOoookc4YIP%2FejMy9xqJ4XEGth0UP3O6noRgBfISjD%2FrHYYBwd5haZaDSkiqlVoruL%2BiTl5oobD9lEFLjB5%2ByYGQfjerpaSQouHi4h2b67X2RSpwtAPcoTs9Bcaw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20191230T142554Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY4Q7RJIFG%2F20191230%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=d4b71eb0e43c00f684703b629724ca0299af6cd3dc35899d3f44428c5d12dfa6&hash=d5258c122f770e14db6c631d9c2c92d642fbbd8455be4da21f87d2b14cf46209&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0047259X91900616&tid=spdf-d059227c-c5ec-46c9-8431-da79d7b4dd94&sid=5341647e76ffe149f4091fa243d9d83a4e25gxrqa&type=client)(pages 277) states that 
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
(P_km)(x)=\bar{b}_k'\bar{A}_k^{-1}B_k(x)
\end{equation}
where $\bar{b}_k'=\int_0^1m(x)B_k(x)dx,\bar{A}_k=\int_0^1B_k(x)B_k'(x)dx$, and $B_k(x)$ is B-splines of degree $v$.

I am not sure how to obtain equation(2) from (1), which looks like a least squares estimator,but in intergral format.

Comment: It is the least square etimator. Try to solve the problem in a matricial form. You will see that this is the operator equivalent of the matricial solution..

Comment: If $K$ is the dimensio of $S_{k,v}$ then $B_k (x) = (\delta_1(x), \ldots, \delta_K(x))$ where $\{\delta_k\}$ are a basis of $S_{k,v}$

Comment: @Manuel Hello, Manuel. I know that the least squares estimator of a function using B splines is $B_k'(x)(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$, where X is $n\times K$ design matrix. But I don not know why equation (2) is in intergral form.

Comment: The formula you know is when you have the values of  $\lambda$ over a grid. This problem is a different because you know the hole $\lambda$.

Comment: You are going for $\|  \lambda - \sum_{i=1}^K a_i \delta_i\|$ if you expand this you will see how integrals appear in you design matrix.

Comment: Also try to sole the problem with the squared norm.